# How do we get a translation in the view on render for a rails model attr, eg a blog post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize, traco

I want to translate a column in rails upon display in the view that is translated to the current users locale IE I don't need to store the translation really in the DB. Is there any reason why gems like `Globalize` and `Traco` force you to store the translation in a separate table on save?

Is there just a way to translate what I want in the view when I render my blog post?

I havn't done any language conversion before in rails but it seems YAML files are just for static text IE we can't add in model objects and translate them?

Comment: "Is there any reason why gems like Globalize and Traco force you to store the translation in a separate table on save?" - Yes. Because its a sane design decision. If you where to store the translations on the same table as the records you need to add `attributes*languages` number of columns to the table and then monkey around with metaprogramming to gather up all the translations off the objects. Adding an additional language would require you to do models * attributes migrations.

Comment: While you could do this if you had one or two attributes that you need to translate to a limited set of languages from a library design standpoint it would be a disaster.

Comment: I was not asking why they store it in a separate db table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this else where where I asked a question..

[Goolge translate](https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/howto_google_translate.asp)

Does the job I need.

Don't think globalize is even is a translator library and going off the railscast 338 seems you still need to add your own translation ymls unless thats just for custom languages I'm not sure exactly how that works. But still you need to translate and save each language just for your model methods to translate